# My <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='tel:+somenumber'" /> tag doesn't working on my Wordpress site

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, meta-tags

I have a wordpress site on my own. i am trying to use in  meta refresh tag like this:

```
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='tel:+somenumber'" />
```

but it doesnt work when i inspect my online webpage in head its http-equiv lost like:

```
<meta content="0; URL='tel:somenumber'"/>
```

when i try to edit as html and insert again

```
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='tel:+somenumber'" />
```

it works. How can i fix this? I am using Head & Footer Extension for Wordpress.

meta http-equiv refresh doesnt working on my wordpress site.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the plugin you use strips the attribute. no need to use a plugin for that, you can add it using this code in the child theme's functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'refresh_meta', 1 );
function refresh_meta() {
   ?>
   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='tel:+somenumber'" />
   <?php
}
```